# Filter an array with multiple conditions fetched from user

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to filter an array of objects based on users' inputs. At the moment, I have a simple array.filter on my search btn function handler, see below:

Array Example:

```
const items = [
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Pad Thai',
        imageUrl:
            'https://www.2foodtrippers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Delicious-Thai-Food-Pad-Thai.jpg.webp',
        country: 'Thailand',
        price: 5,
        description: 'Street food in Bankok',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Canned coffee',
        imageUrl:
            'https://331mrnu3ylm2k3db3s1xd1hg-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Sprudge-VendingMachineCoffee-KateBeard-sprudgevending-3-740x493.jpg',
        country: 'Japan',
        price: 3.5,
        description: 'Had to have one of this in Tokyo',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Scooter day rental',
        imageUrl:
            'https://anomadsdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/SAM_1859.jpg',
        country: 'Vietnam',
        price: 7.5,
        description:
            'Cheap rental bike, Ko Thao. This is average price around Thailand',
        category: 'Transport',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Bottle of Water Price',
        imageUrl:
            'https://2reb5l2d3joj3y7m8y2f5ptbefc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/order/files/2017/11/B1.jpg',
        country: 'Thailand',
        price: 5,
        description: 'Street food Pad Thai',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Gold Ice Cream',
        imageUrl:
            'https://kaname-inn.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_4388_11.jpg',
        country: 'Japan',
        price: 5,
        description: 'Delicious golden ice cream in Kyoto',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Buddah bracelet',
        imageUrl:
            'https://c7.alamy.com/comp/M8XGMD/seoul-south-korea-march-6-2018-buddhist-bracelet-on-shop-at-jogyesa-M8XGMD.jpg',
        country: 'Japan',
        price: 5,
        description: 'Bought this while street shopping in Seoul',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Suvarnabhumi Taxi',
        imageUrl:
            'https://static.bangkokpost.com/media/content/20160507/c1_962249_160507092902.jpg',
        country: 'Thailand',
        price: 5,
        description: 'Taxi from the center Bankok',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
    {
        id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
        itemTitle: 'Vietnamese Coffee',
        imageUrl:
            'https://thewoksoflife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/vietnamese-coffee-7.jpg',
        country: 'Vietnam',
        price: 3.5,
        description: 'Delicious! prices change but this is the average',
        category: 'Food/Beverage',
    },
];
```

Function Handler

```
const searchBtnHandler = () => {
    const itemElements = document.getElementById('cards-hook').children;
    const countryValue = countryFilterAccess.value;
    const searchCategory = searchCategoryMenu.value;

    const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
        return item.country === countryValue && item.category === searchCategory;

    });
    console.log(filteredItems);
};
```

The country Value and search category are fetch from the page. The filter I have works assuming the user provides both filters (country and category). However, I also want to enable users to choose either of the filters. I have tried this through "if statements" but the array returns empty or "weird" filter settings.

What I want is as follow:

Country is left empty - category is provided
Country is given - category is left empty

Can anyone help? I have seen other responses but they assumed that the filter conditions are given, which is not my case.

Thanks!

Comment: _"I have tried this through "if statements" but the array returns empty or "weird" filter settings"_ - Please add your attempt so we can help you to fix it.

Comment: Using `||` instead of `&&` should work in your filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a dynamic filter, I recommend you to create an object similar to List item, but with the props that you want to filter. For example

```js
const items = [
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Pad Thai',
    imageUrl:
        'https://www.2foodtrippers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Delicious-Thai-Food-Pad-Thai.jpg.webp',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Street food in Bankok',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Canned coffee',
    imageUrl:
        'https://331mrnu3ylm2k3db3s1xd1hg-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Sprudge-VendingMachineCoffee-KateBeard-sprudgevending-3-740x493.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 3.5,
    description: 'Had to have one of this in Tokyo',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Scooter day rental',
    imageUrl:
        'https://anomadsdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/SAM_1859.jpg',
    country: 'Vietnam',
    price: 7.5,
    description:
        'Cheap rental bike, Ko Thao. This is average price around Thailand',
    category: 'Transport',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Bottle of Water Price',
    imageUrl:
        'https://2reb5l2d3joj3y7m8y2f5ptbefc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/order/files/2017/11/B1.jpg',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Street food Pad Thai',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Gold Ice Cream',
    imageUrl:
        'https://kaname-inn.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_4388_11.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Delicious golden ice cream in Kyoto',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Buddah bracelet',
    imageUrl:
        'https://c7.alamy.com/comp/M8XGMD/seoul-south-korea-march-6-2018-buddhist-bracelet-on-shop-at-jogyesa-M8XGMD.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Bought this while street shopping in Seoul',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Suvarnabhumi Taxi',
    imageUrl:
        'https://static.bangkokpost.com/media/content/20160507/c1_962249_160507092902.jpg',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Taxi from the center Bankok',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Vietnamese Coffee',
    imageUrl:
        'https://thewoksoflife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/vietnamese-coffee-7.jpg',
    country: 'Vietnam',
    price: 3.5,
    description: 'Delicious! prices change but this is the average',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
},
];


// filter function
const filterFn = (filters) => {
  const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => !Boolean(Object.entries(filters).find(([key, value]) => item[key] !== value)))
  return filteredItems
}

const filtersByCountryAndCategory = {
    country: 'Vietnam',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
}
const filtersByCountryAndPrice = {
  price: 5,        
  category: 'Food/Beverage',
}

console.log("******* BY COUNTRY AND CATEGORY **********");
console.log(filterFn(filtersByCountryAndCategory));

console.log("******* BY CATEGORY AND PRICE **********");
console.log(filterFn(filtersByCountryAndPrice));
```

Answer (score 1):

My Final code works! See final snipped:

```
const filteredItems = (countryValue, searchCategory) => {
    if (countryValue && searchCategory) {
        return items.filter(
            (item) =>
                item.country === countryValue && item.category === searchCategory
        );
    }
    if (countryValue) {
        return items.filter((item) => item.country === countryValue);
    }
    return items.filter((item) => item.category === searchCategory);
};

const searchBtnHandler = () => {
    const itemElements = document.getElementById('cards-hook').children; //this is for the dom
    const countryValue = countryFilterAccess.value.trim();
    const searchCategory = searchCategoryMenu.value.trim();
    const results = filteredItems(countryValue, searchCategory);

    console.log(results);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
        return (countryValue === "" || item.country === countryValue) && (searchCategory === "" || item.category === searchCategory);
    });
```

(Edit: HTML <input> return empty string when there is no value in them)

Comment: this is wrong, what if you enter only a country you should filter all that country if yoiu enter just categories you should get all those categories

Comment: Hi @EugenSunic, but this is what this condition achieves! It only filters a property if the user specified a value for that property.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use this code but when I compare the inputs to null I get false with an input value or not, not sure why... I was expecting null if the string was empty but the console yields false when I compare it to null (console.log(countryvalue === null) Should I use == instead? thanks!

Comment: I tried the following but the country AND category doesn't work... any ideas?  

const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
  return (
   item.country === countryValue ||
   item.category === searchCategory ||
   (item.country === countryValue && item.category === searchCategory)
  );

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answer. I just tested and inputs will return an empty string `""` when empty. I said at the end you might need to check for other values because I didn't have the time to try myself, sorry about that.

What you are looking at is `(countryValue === "" || item.country === countryValue) && (searchCategory === "" || item.category === searchCategory);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use if cases for each criteria, here is an example:

```js
const items = [{
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Pad Thai',
    imageUrl: 'https://www.2foodtrippers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Delicious-Thai-Food-Pad-Thai.jpg.webp',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Street food in Bankok',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Canned coffee',
    imageUrl: 'https://331mrnu3ylm2k3db3s1xd1hg-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Sprudge-VendingMachineCoffee-KateBeard-sprudgevending-3-740x493.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 3.5,
    description: 'Had to have one of this in Tokyo',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Scooter day rental',
    imageUrl: 'https://anomadsdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/SAM_1859.jpg',
    country: 'Vietnam',
    price: 7.5,
    description: 'Cheap rental bike, Ko Thao. This is average price around Thailand',
    category: 'Transport',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Bottle of Water Price',
    imageUrl: 'https://2reb5l2d3joj3y7m8y2f5ptbefc-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/order/files/2017/11/B1.jpg',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Street food Pad Thai',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Gold Ice Cream',
    imageUrl: 'https://kaname-inn.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/IMG_4388_11.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Delicious golden ice cream in Kyoto',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Buddah bracelet',
    imageUrl: 'https://c7.alamy.com/comp/M8XGMD/seoul-south-korea-march-6-2018-buddhist-bracelet-on-shop-at-jogyesa-M8XGMD.jpg',
    country: 'Japan',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Bought this while street shopping in Seoul',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Suvarnabhumi Taxi',
    imageUrl: 'https://static.bangkokpost.com/media/content/20160507/c1_962249_160507092902.jpg',
    country: 'Thailand',
    price: 5,
    description: 'Taxi from the center Bankok',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
  {
    id: Math.random().toFixed(5),
    itemTitle: 'Vietnamese Coffee',
    imageUrl: 'https://thewoksoflife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/vietnamese-coffee-7.jpg',
    country: 'Vietnam',
    price: 3.5,
    description: 'Delicious! prices change but this is the average',
    category: 'Food/Beverage',
  },
];


function filteredItems(countryValue, searchCategory) {
  if (countryValue && searchCategory) {
    return items.filter(item => item.country === countryValue && item.category === searchCategory);
  }
  if (countryValue) {
    return items.filter(item => item.country === countryValue);
  }
  return items.filter(item => item.category === searchCategory);

}

//example 1
let countryValue = "Vietnam"
let searchCategory = ""
console.log(filteredItems(countryValue, searchCategory));

//example 2
let country = "Vietnam"
let category = "Transport"
console.log(filteredItems(country, category));

//example 3
countryValue = ""
searchCategory = "Transport"
console.log(filteredItems(countryValue, searchCategory));
```

Comment: Yes!!!! This worked! thank you so much brother :) ! I just had to store this into a constant and then I can use the array for further tasks!